# How to get value from the plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple plug-in.

```
jQuery.fn.mask = function(options) 
    {
        var mask = '#mask';

        var options = jQuery.extend
            ({
                maskWidth : 800,
                maskHeight : 600,
                maskBgcolor : 'silver',
            }, options);


        return this.each(function()
        {            
            jQuery(this).append('<div id="mask"></div>');

            jQuery(mask)                                                                    
                        .css('width', options.maskWidth)
                        .css('height', options.maskHeight)                                                                                 
                        .css('background-color', options.maskBgcolor) 
        });
    };
```

Calling plug-in

```
$('body').mask();
```

How can I get, for example, the width of "#mask".

Something like this

```
var w = $(this).mask('width') / / in the variable - 800
```

Or other way...

What code should write a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of data do you want to call for? if it's appearance data the easiest thing to do would be to call the JQuery's css function. (on the 'Mask' div).